# drools I added the break keyword after the from xxx keyword and reported an error

Tags: drools

exception:  mismatched input '[' in rule "checkTicketExpired"]
why????

```
rule "checkTicketExpired"
when
    $r: RuleResult(holder instanceof Ticket)
    $ticket: Ticket() from $r.holder
    Ticket(LocalDateTime.now() > expireAt) from $ticket break[expire]
  then
  then[noting]
    .....
  then[expire]
    .....
  then[unAffect]
    ....
end
```

Comment: Your 'break' makes no sense. What are you trying to do? That's the end of the conditional anyway. (Also you spelled 'nothing' wrong, which is not relevant to the question)

Comment: Also the Drools docs only show usage of `break` in a if/else-if setup, which makes sense given what 'break'd does. Trying doing an `if(...) break[expire]`

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas For example, the judgment condition of expiration, I want to terminate the condition when the coupon has expired, do not go down to judge, and finally the correct result is not reached when the condition is reached

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Do I have to use if expressions?

Comment: Yes. Unless you are using `do`.

Comment: If you read the Drools documentation it explains why though not in detail. `break` stops evaluation if the condition matches, so if you use it without a condition then the rest of the left hand side does not evaluate.